# Convert JSON String to Table

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, spring-mvc

**Hi guys! Maybe you can help me**
Now my json response from service is : {"Security":450,"Economical":1850,"IT":1233}
I need to parse it to html table.
I think that i responce my json from rest service in wrong way.
At least i need list of json objects. But i dont know how to do it.
My goal is return NAME of Departments(DEPARTMENTS entity) and AVERAGE SALARY FROM Worker entity. And i have no idea how to make the list of objects in my json file, when i call get method on my service
Here are  my sources:
**DEPARTMENT ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="departments")
public class Department implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
//getters setters....
```

**WORKER ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workers")
public class Worker {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String fio;

@ManyToOne
private Department department;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer salary;
//getters setters....
```

**My service(DepartmentService.class) method which returns my data from mysql**

```
  @Override
public List<Object[]> getAllDepartments() {
    List<Object[]> list;
    Query query =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT dp.name, avg (wr.salary) FROM Worker wr join wr.department dp GROUP BY dp.name");
    list =  query.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

**And my Contollers method which returns json object(jackson library)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonNode getAllDeps() {
    List<Object[]> list  = departmentService.getAllDepartments();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(list.size());
    for (Object[] result : list)
        resultMap.put((String)result[0], ((Double)result[1]).intValue() );
    final JsonNode json = objectMapper.valueToTree(resultMap);
    return json;
}
```

As results i want to get from my service json with list of objects like:
*[{name:"Security",salary:"1500"},{name:"Economical",salary:1850}..],* 
 for parse them to html table with two columns,after succes on jquery ajax call:

but now i have that:

*{"Security":1500,"Economical":1850,"IT":2000}*
and i dont know how to parse it.

I have two questions:
1) how to make, that my java spring controller returns list of objects in json file like: [{name:"Security",salary:"1500"},{name:"Economical",salary:1850}..]
2)how to parse it in table , on succes jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "http://localhost:8081/all",
   success: function(data){        
     //code.....
   }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why this question was discredited. It is obvious you know what you were asking, but didn't know how to ask it... I would suggest you look at my answer and adjust your question just a tad and ask about javascript questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a few different questions here... It seems you understand java pretty well, but javascript it seems is not your forte...

JQuery has a json.parse method as does ecmascript.

Remember, with rest.. it doesn't have ANYTHING to do with the UI. It is simply a service call returning data.

So on your actual ui, you will have to do something with that data... heres some jquery that may work...

```
$.getJSON( "www.mydomain.com/all", function(data) {

    var rows = [];

    $.each(data, function(obj, index){
        rows.push('<tr><td>' + obj.Security + '</td><td>' + obj.Economical + '</td><td>' + obj.IT + '</td></tr>');
    });

    $( '<table/>', {
        'class': 'my-pretty-table',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('#divWhereTableShouldGo');
});
```

Comment: its been a while since I used jquery, that may not compile, but I have plenty of example code using angular.

Comment: Thx for your responce.
I recreate my question.Maybe you can help me with that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819442/convert-listobject-to-json