# Convert List<Object[]> to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

**Hi guys!**

Can someone helps me, how to convert my HQL query results to JSON with list of objects and get it with rest service.

**Here is my service method which returns qyery result list:**

```
   @Override
    public List<Object[]> getAllDepartments() {
        List<Object[]> list;
        Query query =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT dp.name, avg (wr.salary) FROM Worker wr join wr.department dp GROUP BY dp.name");
        list =  query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
```

**And my Spring RESTfull Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonNode getAllDeps() {
    List<Object[]> list  = departmentService.getAllDepartments();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(list.size());
    for (Object[] result : list)
        resultMap.put((String)result[0], ((Double)result[1]).intValue() );
    final JsonNode json = objectMapper.valueToTree(resultMap);
    return json;
}
```

Now my service responce me json with data in thats look :
{"Security":1500,"Economical":1850,"IT":2000}

But i need in that(list of objects):

[{name:"Security",salary:"1500"},{name:"Economical",salary:1850},{name:"IT",salary:2000}]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return the list from the controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Object[]> getAllDeps() {
    List<Object[]> list  = departmentService.getAllDepartments();
    return list;
}
```

The `@ResponseBody` annotation does the transformation for you.

Comment: thx, i cant to check  it right  now.
maybe you also tell me how to parse that  json  to html  table with two  columns(name, avg salary) after jquery ajax succes call to my service?

Comment: Please ask another question for that.

Comment: yeah you are using rest... rest is not an mvc concept... does not even particularly mean you are talking to a browser... simply an http client. it is a data ... or state transfer mechnism. The data representation you chose is JSON. (which evgeni forgot to put in his request mapping) ... it is up to you to do something on the javascript side in order to make your table... or use a java based mvc framework.

Comment: I already check you answer, but my json file look like:
[["Economical",1850.0],["IT",1233.3333],["Security",450.0]], and not like 
[{name:"Security",salary:"1500"},{name:"Economical",salary:1850},{name:"IT",salary:2000}]

Comment: this is not the correct answer, it returns an array of properties not an object, as @MeetJoeBlack explains.

Answer (score 0):

```
public JSONObject findOccurrByFileUUID(UUID filePefin) throws JSONException {

    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
    strQuery.append("SELECT c.\"name\" AS creditorname, d.\"name\" AS debtorname, concat(b2.\"type\",'-',b2.\"number\",'-',b2.parcel) AS docto, b2.uniquenumber, to_char(b.dateoccurr,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS dateoccur, to_char(b.createddate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS createddate, b.statusnegatived, l.username FROM billnegativedoccurr b \n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN billnegatived b2 ON b2.uuid = b.billnegativeduuid \n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN creditor c ON c.tenantowner_uuid = b2.tenant_uuid AND c.uuid = b2.creditor_uuid \n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN debtor d ON d.tenantowner_uuid = b2.tenant_uuid AND d.uuid = b2.debtor_uuid \n" +
                    "INNER JOIN login l ON l.uuid = b.useroccurr \n" +
                    "WHERE b.filepefinuuid = :filePefin");

    Query query = eM.createNativeQuery(strQuery.toString()); //no entity mapping
    query.setParameter("filePefin", filePefin);
    List<Object[]> queryList = query.getResultList();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    for (Object[] result : queryList) {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("creditorName", result[0]);
        object.put("debtorName", result[1]);
        object.put("docto", result[2]);
        object.put("uniquenumber", result[3]);
        object.put("dateoccur", result[4]);
        object.put("createddate", result[5]);
        object.put("statusnegatived", result[6]);
        object.put("username", result[7]);

        array.put(object);
    }

    return obj.put("Values", array);
}
```

Comment: Try doing it this way. Adapt to your reality.